# Check if csv contains Chinese characters in python then output

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file that contains English and Chinese, how can I separate them and then save the ones that contain Chinese as "Chinese" and those that don't contain Chinese as "English",
I found a code to differentiate but I don't know how to save them.

```
def is_chinese(string):
    for ch in string:
        if u'\u4e00' <= ch <= u'\u9fff':
            return True

    return False

ret1 = is_chinese("a中国aaa")
print(ret1)

ret2 = is_chinese("123")
print(ret2)
```

csv file

```
"sex","name","age"
"1","hali","18"
"2","张三","24"
"1","云lee","20"
```

I want to classify it like this：
Eeglish

```
"sex","name","age"
"1","hali","18"
```

Chinese：

```
"sex","name","age"
"2","张三","24"
"1","云lee","20"
```

Comment: If you already have the way to identify the characters, I'd suggest learning about [writing to files in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files).

Comment: What is your desired input and output? Give an example.  How do you want to separate them?  Iterate by row and write rows containing Chinese to a different file?

Comment: @MarkTolonen ok i updated the thread, you can see it in the question,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code output the lines that contains the chinese character and save those into a file called "detected.txt"

```
import re

characters=[]
i = 0
with open('01.csv','r',encoding='utf-8') as file: #Open CSV file
    with open('detected.txt', 'r+') as f: #Open file to write

        for line in file.readlines(): #Read each line of CSV file
            if re.findall(r'[\u4e00-\u9fff]+', line) == []: #If there is no Chinese character in the line
                pass
            else:
                characters.append(re.findall(r'[\u4e00-\u9fff]+', line)) #Append the Chinese character to the list
                if str(characters[i][0]) in line: #If the Chinese character is in the line
                    f.write(line) #Append the line to the file
                i+=1
```

Comment: The code works fine, but it doesn't output lines containing Chinese characters, only Chinese characters, I need to save lines containing Chinese characters, sorry for not expressing clearly before

Comment: I checked it, it works great, it would be better if it could save English and Chinese separately, upvoted for you,

Comment: just open other file and write 'line' after the if